# Handling JDBC Exceptions

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing one JDBC exception (once in 100 times).
But even in that case, I want to take control of that exception and make the process smooth

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:67)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3559)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3445)
at oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getTables(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:2766)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:70)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.statusOnException(DefaultConnectionTester.java:59)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnection$ProxyConnectionInvocationHandler.handleMaybeFatalToPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnection.java:837)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnection$ProxyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(C3P0PooledConnection.java:732)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.$Proxy55.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:232)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:581)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:843)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:288)
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is not a JDBC exception. In fact it's not exception at all. It's an error. I added you the relevant tag and suggest you read the relevant questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in not an SQLException. Your problem here lies with your JDBC driver which is not available to your application. In other words you are trying to use something (driver) that doesn't exist.

Solution:

1)Make sure you have the proper JDBC driver form Oracle ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html )

2) Make sure you make available the driver to your application

Here is a good place to start http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html

Comment: But I am getting the connection 99 times. Once in a while it's failing. any specific reason?

Comment: if you are getting connection for single time also, the drivers and all are there. The only thing that may happen is the mistake in your class design or misuse of some resource.